# Postgresql multiple conditional where clause with different limits

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I need to fetch data from a table with multiple if conditions. I have 3 tables: Questions, levels, difficulty_levels using which I need to fetch the data.

EG:
`Select * 
from questions q 
join level l on l.id = q.level_id
join difficulty_level dl on dl.id = q.difficulty_level_id
where:
1. difficulty_level = 'easy', limit l.easy_question_count
2. difficulty_level = 'medium', limit l.medium_question_count
3. difficulty_level = 'hard', limit l.hard_question_count
and l.id = some_id`

Is there a way in which I can fetch the data in a single query?

Comment: I suspect you have more requirements than you describe, since three limits to a single query do not make sense. I suspect you want to combine three limited sets to a single result set. Take a look at subqueries for that and combine the results using a `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you. Your suspicion is right. I need to combine 3 sets of data from the same table with different condition. Union makes sense but since I'll be needing the same set out data, from the same table, is there any other way I can do this in a single query? Also, can I put a variable (using data of 1 column) in limit, instead of the usual number?

Comment: I also need to randomise the output data set for each condition

Comment: You need three separate subqueries, since you want separate limits. That gives you three sets which have to be combined somehow.

Comment: You might be able to "simulate" the separate limits inside a single query using a counter column iterating a number per row in combination with the difficulty column if you define conditionals on that combination inside the WHERE clause. But that will be much less efficient, so: _why_?

Comment: I am trying to build a system for a game. I need to fetch limited questions from each level (easy, medium, hard). So, say the limits are set to easy=10, medium=2 and hard=0, I need 12 questions in total (10+2). this number is saved in a table and is variable. I have a feeling, that the query is going to be very complex but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: @arkascha is correct: `UNION`ing three queries, one for each difficulty level, is the way to get the list of questions. But there is no efficient way to interpolate the limits in a single query; your best bet is to retrieve the limits for the level ahead of time and build the unioned query dynamically. `ORDER BY random()` in each subquery gives you the sorting.